# Added series does not remains in highcharts on show/hide of chart container

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using [addSeries](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.addSeries) feature of highcharts to add series dynamically. It is working perfectly when we add series, problem occurs when we show/hide container of the charts added series disappears.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-x-range-highcharts-h7aoha?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

App.component

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  chart: any = {};
  dip: boolean = true;
  saveInstance(chartInstance): void {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
  }
  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },

      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
      }]
    };
  }
  options: Object;
  addSeries() {
    this.chart.addSeries({
      data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    });
  }
  toggle() {
    this.dip = !this.dip;
  }
}
```

**How to retain added series even we show/hide chart container?**

Note: In real case the series are added dynamically (there are no predefined values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentations states that n*g-show (and its sibling ng-hide ) toggle the appearance of the element by adding the CSS display: none style. ng-if , on the other hand, actually removes the element from the DOM when the condition is false and only adds the element back once the condition turns true*.

So, you have to work with `hidden` or `display` property from CSS. Below you have some code snippets:

Option 1:

```
<div [style.display]="!dip ? 'block' : 'none'">
   <chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event.context)" ></chart>
</div>
```

Option 2:

```
<div [hidden]="dip">
    <chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event.context)" ></chart>
</div>
```

Demo: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-x-range-highcharts-mgidqc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-x-range-highcharts-jrtvr2

Instead of

```
<div *ngIf="dip">
```

use

```
 <div [hidden]="dip">
```

Actually whenever you are clicking on that button its loading the chart again. So its better to show and hide via display instead of loading.